# ViewPager dissapears when wrapping it inside ScrollView

Tags: android

I have a Linear Layout inside a scroll View. when specify ` android:layout_height="wrap_content" for ViewPager it disappears until set literal values instead. i dont know why?
my xml code:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    .....

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/moto" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewshop_pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/viewshop_pagerStrip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="@color/blueStrip"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" />

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can u post ur complete xml?

Comment: just deleted some text views and buttons and still not works its complete code

Comment: Can u change linear layout height to match parent and add  android:fillViewport="true" to scrollview and try.

Comment: view pager loads then some fragments thats not the matter . without ScrollView or by setting some values like "200dp" etc it works fine.

Comment: thank you so much . its exactly what i want.

Comment: but why you are putting vuew pager in scrollview?? Add the fragment that will be loaded in view pager in scrollview

Comment: my viewPager has four tabs or pages that must be swiped and if pages contents be much . it must be scrolled something like twitter app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching around the web and by helps of stack friends decided to use

```
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
```

then

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
```

inside it

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
```

for collapsing after scroll and then add my viewPager
thanks to this code in GitHub:
[CollapsingToolbarLayout with TabLayout](https://gist.github.com/iPaulPro/1468510f046cb10c51ea)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. and let me know.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    .....

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/moto" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewshop_pager"
        android:layout_width=" match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/viewshop_pagerStrip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="@color/blueStrip"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" />

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for your attention .but @Raghavendra answer resolved my problem. must add  android:fillViewport="true" to scrollview

Comment: not works . by adding android:fillViewport="true" it shows the viewpager but scroll not works